# Firebase correct logic

Tags: firebase

Wondering if I have the right mindset here... In firebase (with Vue) I have a userscollection:

```
users : {
    uid: "09A09IQMSLDK0912",
    name: "Gerard",
    email: "gerard@mail.com"
}
```

If I want the user to add friends, should I add it to the userscollection?

```
users : {
    uid: "09A09IQMSLDK0912",
    name: "Gerard",
    email: "gerard@mail.com",
    friends: []
}
```

... or should I start a new collection (e.g. friendscollection)?

```
friends: {
    {
        userId : 09A09IQMSLDK0912,
        friendId: 09A09IQMSLDAEAQS
    }
 }
```

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Which database are you using? The Realtime database or Firestore?

Comment: That totally depends on what you want to do next, if you want to get names of the friends of a user easily, saving their names/ids in the `friends: [..]` like this, should be what you'd do. If you want to do something else which requires you to have userId and FriendsID stored at some place, second way would be the one you should go for. That's the thing about Firebase (nosql), you can always structure according to your requirements.

Comment: I will need to get the name, email, ... indeed after saving it.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add it as a new collection. You shouldn't model any of your collections to have an array property that can have an endless amount of items in it, otherwise, you will run into issues at scale.

Instead, you should create another collection and have them relate via ID as you mentioned.

I am not an expert on a Firebase DB but I know it functions very similarly to a MongoDB. For example, say the DB is a MongoDB. There is a limit to how large a collection item can be (BSON Limit: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) and if you allow a collection item to have an array property that can grow indefinitely, you will quickly reach this limit and you wont able to insert the item into the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to store each user's friends in your Firebase Database in a similar structure to this:

```
   friends: {
        userId1: {
            friend1UserId: 123123123121 // timestamp of when the users became friends, or whatever value is useful to your application.
            friend2UserId: 123123123123 
            friend3UserId: 213123123123
        }
        userId2: {
            friend1UserId: 412124124124
            friend2UserId: 213123213321
        }
   }
```

This is because Firebase is very limited with querying - and generally in a NoSQL database you would like to keep you data as **wide** as possible rather than going **deeper**.